# How to move database from one SQL Server 2008 R2 machine to another?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration

I have to move a database from one SQL Server 2008 R2 to another.

How can I perform this task?

Someone suggest me to make backup form first server and restore on the second server.

May be this correct?

Comment: backup on server A then restore on server B, so yes, the suggestion was good.

Comment: I don't know if this is a concern for the questioner, but the trouble I personally have with this task is when moving from one domain to another. I get all kinds of difficulties because I'm not sure how to also move the users/roles data along with the dbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities, depending on your constraints.

- you can use the detach/attach method
- you can use the backup/restore method
- you can use the Copy Database Wizard in SSMS